# It´s possible to get form token - Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working with Symfony 4, and I want to make my own form but to make an insert i need a token that is generated by the form, there is a way to generate  the form and get the or what else i can do.

```
public function new(Request $request): Response
{
    $customer = new Customers();



    $form = $this->createForm(Customers1Type::class, $customer); // <- here
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($customer);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('customers_index');
    }

    return $this->render('customers/new.html.twig', [
        'customer' => $customer,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean CSRF token or what? And why would you need that?

Comment: @revengeance yes, the  CSRF token.

Answer (score 0):

You basically do not need to get and render the token by yourself. Symfony forms handle that internally and the form_end function renders the hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

When you inspect the generated Form, you will see:

```
<input type="hidden" id="customer__token" name="customer[_token]" value="the_long_token_auto_generated" /></form>
```

Then inside your controller action's, you can get the token by the $request method's:

```
$token = $request->request->get('customer')['_token'];
```

Comment: thank you but i'm using a form builded for me, so i need the token before submit , and as i see i can get it in the request after submit.